# Add colors to a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-spinner

Add colors to a spinner

I am new to Android Studio and I want to do something that I hope it's not to complicated.
I would like to add an option of choosing color.
In other words: a spinner where the fields are "color squares"
like in the case of choosing color for the boots:
http://www.nextdirect.com/us/en/g88104s9#660994

And how can I convert this color to text values, for example: If the user chooses red, I will get 'red'.

I hope someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is put an image with the color would be the easiest you pass these links so you can guide yourself because it is pretty code

[Spinner](https://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/download/4-tutorials/39-spinner-tutorial.html)

[Android Spinner customized](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-Spinner-customized-to-show-image-and-text.htm)